# What's the best way to keep track of visitors for a shopping cart application?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a shopping car application and I would like visitors (i.e. people not logged in) to be able to add items to the shopping cart without logging in. Of course, they would be asked to log in if they wish to checkout. Currently I have it setup so that the shopping cart is associated with the persons user id on the site, but like I said I'd like to allow visitors to add items to the cart as well.

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple: use sessions.

Presumably you're already doing that for logged in users, so you should know how they work. But sessions have nothing to do with being logged in, they can be used to simply accumulate information for any user.

Comment: Actually, I'm not familiar with sessions at all. I am using a CMS on my website that handles user logins and I'm writing my application on top of that framework, so to speak. I will look into sessions, though. Thank you.